# 0xc000007b error when trying to open a few programs (on Windows 10 x64)

Tags: windows, 64-bit

It pops up when I try to open Adobe Audition, my printer software, etc.
[Dependency Walker report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OmV8.png)

Comment: So first dependency walker will give false positive of missing files at times.  Have you tried to simply reinstall Adobe Audition?  Those errors opening files is a false positive and known software defect with Dependency Walker.

Comment: I did. And the same continues.

Comment: Here is an article taking about error code: 0xc000007b, you could check if methods in it were helpful to you: [Fix "The application was unable to start (0xc000007b)" error in Windows](https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/fix-error-code-0xc000007b.php)

Answer (score 0):

The Dependency Walker report does not show any abnormal errors.
The errors that alarmed you are entirely normal.
The Dependency Walker is not a perfect tool and its report is hard to read.

There are several reasons for the 0xc00007b error.
The most common cause of this issue is the incompatibility between the
32/64-bit application and the 32/64-bit architecture of your system.

An example of this is when a 32-bit application tries to execute itself on
a 64-bit system and vice versa. In other words, there is a mixture of software
blocks, each compiled for a different architecture.

I suggest to uninstall the software in question and then reinstall,
after ensuring that all the architectures match your computer.
Check specifically all Adobe products that you have installed, so they are
all of the bitness.